# Leaflet appears as Grey Box and Zoom not working

Tags: google-maps, location, javascript

I am using geofield and leaflet.widget in a content type field. I have a leaflet view containing nodes with these field locations.

Upon displaying the view at first a grey box appears in place of the leafletmap. One click of the zoom (plus or minus) triggers the appearance of the map. But thereafter the zoom then does not work. Clicking plus or minus does nothing. This is happening both to the display of leaflet fields in rendered nodes and to the leaflet view.

Setting the Initial Zoom Level to 13 will at least allow the map to appear. But this only works on views with one vectored location and not on views with many vectored locations.

I have tried using both ESRI World Street Map and Google Road Map.

Comment: I am kinda new to leaflet so I am not sure how helpful I will be but I'll take a shot at your question. Since you are having difficulty loading the map tiles I would say that one of the problems could be the leaflet library itself. Is the leaflet library properly installed? If so, the second thing that I would try is installing a module called Leaflet more maps module. Using this module will give you access to a bunch of different basemaps. After installing this module you may have the ability to render some maps if the normal ones are still not rendering properly.